# Proving the solutions of trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

> If $f(x) =a^{\cos x}$ and $g(x)=(\sin x)^a$, $a \in N$, then prove that $f(x) = g(x)$ for infinitely many values of x.

My Attempt to prove this:
If $f(x) = g(x)$,
$$a^{\cos x} = (\sin x)^a$$
Taking Logs on both sides..
$$\log_a a^{\cos x} = \log_a (\sin x)^a$$
$$\cos x = a\log_a \sin x$$

*This is just my thought process and I am pretty sure that it is wrong. But it may be something along these lines. I do not know how to start thinking about this problem.* Please Help!

Comment: When $\sin x =1$, what is $\cos x$?

Comment: Then, $\cos x = 0$

Comment: And then what is $a^0$ and what is $1^a$?

Comment: Both are 1 and 1

Comment: @Conrad I get where u are going but you are supposed to prove for infinite values of x

Comment: $\sin$ is periodic so if one $x$ satisfies $\sin x=1$, then lots of $x$- infinitely many actually - will too. Can you find them now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi$, with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, you have
$$f(x)=a^{\cos(x)}=a^0=1$$

and

$$g(x)=(\sin(x))^a=1^a=1$$

So here are your infinite values of $x$ where $f(x)=g(x)$.